# Insert query not executing

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert the product the user selected into a table called cart which has two columns: cart_id and item_id_FK both are foreign keys.  User_id and id are passed in the constructor and then inserted into cart_id and item_id_fk. 
No errors are showing in the code, I double checked the connection username and password, everything works fine except for the cart table. 
I tried putting a try and catch statement inside and repeating the steps it didn't work.

```js
if (e.getSource()==AddToCartBtn)
{
//Check to see if item is available 
String SizeSelection;
SizeSelection = SizeCmbx.getSelectedItem().toString();              

String DBURL ="JDBC:MySql://localhost:3306/shoponline?useSSL=true";
String USER ="root";
String PASSWORD ="12345678";
try {
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, USER, PASSWORD);
String sql2 = String.format("select itemid,size,productid_fk from items where size='%s' and productid_fk=%d",SizeSelection,id);
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
String sql3 = "insert into cart (CartID, ItemID_FK)" + " values (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
preparedStmt.setInt(1, user_ID);
preparedStmt.setInt(2, id);
if(result.next())
{
//if item is available 
// execute the preparedstatement
 preparedStmt.execute();
 
}//end if
 con.close();
}// end try
catch (SQLException ex){
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }//end catch
```

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with the sql2 query

Comment: You're inserting the very same record for every row returned by the select. Is that what you want?

Comment: You're also closing the connection after the first insert and you're not committing....

Comment: @RobertKock The select statement will return only one row or none at all since I don't have duplicate rows in the items table.  I tried removing the con.close(); statement but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're not committing the insert. Or do you have the auto-commit active?

Comment: Anyway, change the `while` into an `if` only to make the core more readable. Furthermore, close the connection outside this while/if. Otherwise it remains open also if the query doesn't return anything.

Comment: @RobertKock thanks again for your help.  The auto-commit is active.  I changed the while into an if and closed the connection outside as you suggested but it's still not working.

Comment: Does your result.next() returns anything ? You might want to iterate it independently. 
But it seems executeUpdate() would do the inserts for you

Check this for example: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: As @Amit already suggested, check that `result.next()` returns `true`. Either by means of a debugger or by some print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change executeQuery to executeUpdate:

```
executeQuery(sql3)
```

to

```
executeUpdate(sql3)
```

I believe integers don't need the ' ' around them to be inserted, you may try removing those as well. It may be mistaking them as characters or something similiar.

Otherwise if neither of those above fixes work, try something like this:

```
  String query = "insert into cart (CartID, ItemID_FK)"
            + " values (?, ?)";

          // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
          PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

          preparedStmt.setInt(1, xInt);
          preparedStmt.setInt(2, yInt);

          // execute the preparedstatement
          preparedStmt.execute();

          conn.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried your code it didn't work:( no errors but nothing is inserted in the table.  Help please:(